# How can i configure Shibboleth new v3 IdP with WSO2 Identity Server?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

while configuring using old documentation there is not any step to update idp.war while update in some login.config, handler.xml,

And for Sibboleth new version 3.4.x configure with wso2is 5.x not any documentation  becouse according to old version there is not login.config file in "idp.home/conf"

Comment: It is not clear what do you exactly want to configure and what problem you exactly have. You want to use shibboleth as a SP with WSO2IS as its IdP? you have a problem to configure you application? Shibboleth config? WSO2IS? (you assigned tags of wso2is, but the configuration you mentions has nothing to do with it) You have to be much more specific if you want any reasonable answer

Comment: I have done that thing my next question is after configure Shibboleth IDP with wso2is. There  are two war files travelocity.com.war and idp.war. As per documentation idp.war file running on 8443 port and travelocity.com.war file running on 8080 port. when i only deploy idp.war file it running fine but when i run idp.war on 8443 and travelocity.com.war on 8080 port. idp.war give 404 error

Comment: could you link the documentation you follow?  (do not assume anybody knows what you are reading ) which url gives 404, anything in the logs?...

Comment: am following [http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/12/04/federatation-shibboleth/] but to deploy am using two different apache port for idp.war and travelocity.com.war. because travelocity.com.war internally using 8080 port and in documentation idp.war mention to run on 8443 port